# Intervention Image distorcion al convertir png to jpg

Tags: php, laravel, imagen

Usando Image Intervention estoy convirtiendo cualquier extensión a .jpg pero tengo un resultado no esperado cuando convierto un png.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado que espero es que el fondo sea blanco cuando se convierta a .jpg

este es el codigo que uso para guardar:

```
    $user = Auth::user();

    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {

        $file = $request->file('avatar');
        $name = $user->idPersona.'.jpg';

        Image::make($file)->encode('jpg', 75)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/img/avatars/'.$name) );

        $user->avatar = $name;
    }

    $user->save();
```

Comment: la solución no la sé, pero creo que ese problema es causado por el algoritmo de compresión que utiliza el formato jpg, si es que no existe una solucion dentro de las funciones de esa libreria, la solución sería convertir la imagen en una matriz y reemplazar los espacios vacios (sin color) con un color que tu quieres de relleno(blanco, por ejemplo)